# Question about the projective plane

Tags: geometry

We define the binary operation of a projective plane as follows: Let $x$ and $y$  be any two points in the projective plane (think of the projective plane as an upper hemisphere). Let $y'$ be the antipodal point of $y$ which locates in the lower hemisphere and equal to $y$. Draw a line through $x$ and $y'$. $x*y$ is then defined as the end point of the line parallel to the line joining $x$ and $y'$ with same length and the mid point of it is the origin (Since the end points of this line are antipodal so they are equal in the projective plane).
My question is : Is it true that 
$$x*(y*z)=(x*y)*(x*z)?$$
If so, then please can you guide me how to prove it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: A line through the origin necessarily has length equal to the diameter of the sphere, so it's not clear what you mean by 'same length' and also 'mid point of it is the origin'. Please explain more clearly what the binary operation $*$ is. For instance, what is $[(0,0,1)]*[(0,1,0)]$? (these points are orthogonal so you should be able to explain easily.)

Comment: From what I can get from the construction, $x*y$ is the midpoint of $\bar{xy}$, so $[(0,0,1)]*[(0,1,0)]=[(0,\frac12\sqrt2,\frac12\sqrt2)]$ in the hemisphere, or $(0,1)*(1,0)=(\frac12,\frac12)$ in the plane.

Comment: I agree with carlos. I interpreted "the end point of the line parallel to the line joining x and y′ with same length and the mid point of it is the origin" to be "the end point of the line segment parallel to the line joining x and y′ whose length equal to the diameter of the hemisphere and whose midpoint is the origin."

Comment: So basically if you have $(0,0,1)$, $(1,0,0)$, and $(0,1,0)$ as $x$, $y$, and $z$ repsectively ($x$ is the north pole, $y$ and $z$ are on the equator), then $y*z$ is on the equator, so $x*(y*z)$ is at $45^\circ$ north. On the other hand $x*y$ and $x*z$ are on $45^\circ$ already, so the great circle connecting them goes north of $45^\circ$ north so I get that the identity does not hold. But I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm still not sure this is well-defined. Specifically, for distinct pairs of points on the equator, as each point has two representatives on the equator, the multiplication of any two points has four possible representatives. For instance in the above example we have $y*z=[(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2},\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2},0)]=[(- \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2},- \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2},0)]$ but because $(0,1,0)\sim (0,-1,0)$ we also have $y*z=y*(-z)=[(-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2},\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2},0)] = [(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2},-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2},0)]$ which is not equal to the previous calculation.

Comment: I'm becoming more convinced that this is the midpoint in the arc between $x$ and $y$ in the proyecting hemisphere, which is not the midpoint of the segment in the proyective plane, and also that this is not true for anything but singular cases, v.g. $y=z$